# Getting NullReferenceException on Loading form C#

Tags: c#

When I'm going to load form2 in c#, Im Getting "Null Reference Exception"  When the command

```
a.Show();
```

wants to run.

that is really weird for me

**Codes**

**Form1** on login click

```
     MainForm a = new MainForm();
     a.MyProperty = timeleft;
     a.Show();
     this.Hide();
```

**Form2** Load

```
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    string recievedTime = "#";

 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            recievedTime = MyProperty;
            countdownTimer.Start();
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes("arm.exe", SLN.Properties.Resources.adb);
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes("arm64.dll", SLN.Properties.Resources.arm64);
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/c sc stop KProcessHacker";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Code 10" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that MainForm_Load and inspect your variables, such as countdownTimer

Comment: @HansKeﬆing By Removing All Codes in Form Load Still same Error

Comment: An exception has a stacktrace where you can find the method where the error occurred, what does that say? Then add a breakpoint there and inspect